# Java FX 8 TextArea program showing errors

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to create a TextArea JavaFX 8 program that displays the string in the text area in a label and also reverses the string in the text area. The Gui consists of two buttons and the text area. I have created a JavaFX 8 TextArea program that on compiling is showing the following error.

```
TextAreaDemo1.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
ta.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  ^
  symbol:   method setOnAction(<anonymous EventHandler<ActionEvent>>)
  location: variable ta of type TextArea
1 error
```

This is my  program code:

```
// Demonstrate a text field.

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class TextAreaDemo1 extends Application {

TextArea ta;
Label response;

Button btnGetText;
Button btnReverse;

public static void main(String[] args){

// Start the JavaFX application by calling launch().

launch(args);

}

// Override the start() method.

public void start(Stage myStage){

// Give the stage a title.

myStage.setTitle("Demonstrate a TextArea");

// Use a FlowPane for the root node. In this case,
// vertical and horizontal gaps of 10.

FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10, 10);

// Center the controls in the scene.

rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

// Create a Scene.

Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 230, 140);

// Set the scene on the stage.

myStage.setScene(myScene);

// Create a label that will display the string.

response = new Label("String: ");

// Create a button that gets the text.

btnGetText = new Button("Get String");

// Create button that reverses the text.

btnReverse = new Button("Reverse");

// Create a text field

ta = new TextArea();

// Set the prompt.

ta.setPromptText("Enter a String");

ta.setFocusTraversable(false);

// Set preferred column count.

ta.setPrefRowCount(5);
ta.setPrefColumnCount(10);

// Handle action events for the text field. Action
// events are generated when ENTER is pressed while
// the text area has input focus. In this case, the
// text in the field is obtained and displayed.

ta.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {

response.setText("String: " + ta.getText());

}

});

// Get text from the text field when the button is pressed
// and display it.

btnGetText.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {

response.setText("String: " + ta.getText());

}

});

// Get text from the text field when the button is pressed,
// reverse it using a StringBuilder, and then display it.

btnReverse.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(ta.getText());
ta.setText(str.reverse().toString());

}

});

// Use a separator to better organize the layout.

Separator separator = new Separator();
separator.setPrefWidth(200);

// Add controls to the scene graph.

rootNode.getChildren().addAll(ta, btnGetText, btnReverse, separator, response);

// Show the stage and its scene.

myStage.show();

}

}
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: `setEventHandler` as `setOnAction` is probable from a more current JavaFX. Though the first answer proposes an other event though.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in your code, I see that you are trying to display the text when *enter* is pressed in the TextArea. You should listen to a key press event instead.

Example:

```java
ta.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
             response.setText("String: " + ta.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: TextAreaDemo1.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
ta.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class KeyEvent
  location: class TextAreaDemo1
TextAreaDemo1.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                       ^
  symbol: class KeyEvent
TextAreaDemo1.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
        if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                            ^
  symbol: variable KeyCode
3 errors . The keypressed event handler shows the above error. but on omitting event handler code works

Comment: Import them. @Rohit